# How to creat a slash command in cog

Tags: discord.py

I created a slash command under message cog to clean up messages, but it shows that 'the application is not responding' in discord

Here is my code:

```
class Message(InitCog):

    # clean messages
    @app_commands.command(name='clean', description='clean messages')
    @app_commands.describe(num='number of message')
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def clean(self, ctx, *, num: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num)
        await discord.Interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        await discord.Interaction.followup.send(f'deleted {num} messages')

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Message(client))
```

and main code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def setup_hook():
    for Filename in os.listdir('./cmds'):
        if Filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'cmds.{Filename\[:-3\]}')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    sync = await client.tree.sync()
    print(f"bot logged as {client.user}")
    print(f'synced {len(sync)} commands')

async def main():
    await setup_hook()
    await client.start(jdata\['Token'\])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: 'CachedSlotProperty' object has no attribute 'defer' shown in consle,after i delete code:'await discord.Interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)',it shown 'CachedSlotProperty' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 0):

Already solved , Use interaction.channel.purge instead of ctx.channel.purge

```
@app_commands.command(name='clean', description='clean messages')
@app_commands.describe(num='number of message')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def clean(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, num: int):
    try:
        await interaction.channel.purge(limit=num)
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.followup.send(f'deleted {num} messages')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```